# How to compare List count against single integer value?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to matching total number of records but not able to do it because my one totalcount strong in list type variable and another is getting store in single integer variable.

My Code :

```
`Base.getdriver().get(Js_constants.DashboardURL);

  List<WebElement>  totaljobs = Base.getdriver().findElements(By.className(Js_constants.TopsJobsactualtotal));
  System.out.println(totaljobs.size()); //OUTPUT 30

   //Integer.parseInt(totaljobs); //THIS IS NOT WORKING..WHY?

  String Topjobscount = Base.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath(Js_constants.Topsjobscount)).getText();
  System.out.println(Topjobscount); //OUTPUT 30
  Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount); 



  //HERE IT IS NOT SUPPORTING CONDITION LIKE THIS.
  if(Topjobscount == (totaljobs.size()))

  {

      System.out.println("Jobs & Count are matching");
      Reporter.log("Jobs & Count are matching");

  }
  else
  {

      System.out.println("Jobs & Count are matching");
      Reporter.log("Jobs & Count are not matching");


  }


  }`
```

I am using **selenium webdriver & Java**. I want to compare both variable count but issue is it does not allow me to convert list type variable to integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Topjobscount` varibale is a string and you are trying to compare it with an int value.

Calling `Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount)` wont convert your `string` to `int`.You have to assign the value returned by `Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount)` to an int value and then compare.
Try this.

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount);
if(x == (totaljobs.size()))
```

Remember to catch `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 1):

[Integer.parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) documentation states that

> **Returns:**
>       the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
>
> **Throws:**
>       *NumberFormatException* - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

So you need to save that returned value into Integer variable and use that variable.

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount);
if(count == (totaljobs.size()))
```

Comment: Thank you buddy..:) I was in impression that without saving to variable also it will convert into integer..

Comment: No you can't change String reference(Topjobscount) to Integer reference

Answer (score 0):

> Java is strictly a types language. That means following.
>
> You can not supply anything into a method, it has to be strictly in the same object hierarchy. It results a compile time error if trying to supply wrong type of value as a parameter.

E.g. in your code `List<WebElement>  totaljobs` clearly says type of object **totaljobs** is List.
Where in `Integer.parseInt()` takes a parameter type of **String**. So you can not supply a List type of value where string is expected. 
rather you can pass size of list by converting it in string as shown following.

```
String.valueOf(totaljobs.size());
```

will return a string representation of size of the list.

However you can convert this string value back to integer by calling  `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(totaljobs.size()));`

> But above does not make any sense as **size()** method of List, returns an integer value.
>
> **Topjobscount** is a String value which can not be compared to int value without converting it to integer.

So you can correct `(Topjobscount == (totaljobs.size()))` by converting String into integer. As given below.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(Topjobscount) == totaljobs.size())
```

Hope this helps.